# How to calculate the URL byte length?

Tags: url, byte

can somebody tell me how i can calculate the byte lengths of urls?
The RFC says browsers are only required to support URLs up to 1,024 bytes in length.
But how do i calculate that?

Comment: I don't recall if URLs are ASCII or Unicode. If ASCII, it's just 1 byte for each character. If Unicode, well it's more than 1 byte per character (depending on the exact format).

Comment: URLs aren't unicode.. special characters should be encoded

Comment: oh right, well then I'll post my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In standard ASCII text each character is 1 byte. The browser's URL is standard ASCII (putting Unicode characters in the URL requires special encoding) so there you go.